# How can I make a bash script work correctly when I input an URL as an argument

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script at the moment, and I keep running into a problem when the script will stop and go to the background immediately after starting. I'm pretty sure that this is occurring because the URL is not escaped after I enter it, but I'm not sure how to go about making it, so it will be escaped as soon as I enter it.

I have pasted the code the below as well as what happens when I try to run it. Once again, I really just need help with getting the URL to escape properly upon entry.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

url=$1

if [ "$url" = "" ]; then

        echo "D: you did not supply a url!"
        exit

fi

echo "Please specify your preferred file format by entering the number corresponding to the format name below"
echo "1:avi 2:mp3 3:aac 4:best(program will pick the the best audio format available (aac, mp3, m4a, wav, vorbis))"

read format

if [ "$format" = "1" ]; then

        orders="-qt"

elif [ "$format" = "2" ]; then

        orders="-qt --extract-audio --audio-format mp3"

elif [ "$format" = "3" ]; then

        orders="-qt --extract-audio --audio-format aac"

elif [ "$format" = "4" ]; then

        orders="-qt --extract-audio --audio-format best"

else

        echo "You did not enter a valid option (1,2,3 or 4) :("
        exit

fi

echo "$orders" (debug stuff)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is what happens when I run the script:

```
austin@Ruby:~$ ./meddownload.sh http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g34B-YOaC7c&ob=av2e
```

[1] 1001
austin@Ruby:~$ Please specify your preferred file format by entering the number corresponding to the format name below
1:avi 2:mp3 3:aac 4:best(program will pick the the best audio format available (aac, mp3, m4a, wav, vorbis))
1
    -bash: 1: command not found

```
[1]+  Stopped                 ./meddownload.sh http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g34B-YOaC7c
```

And here is what happens when I enter a non-URL as the argument (this shows that the URL is mostly likely the cause of the problem):

```
austin@Ruby:~$ ./meddownload.sh iuniuniun
Please specify your preferred file format by entering the number corresponding to the format name below
1:avi 2:mp3 3:aac 4:best(program will pick the the best audio format available (aac, mp3, m4a, wav, vorbis))
1
-qt
```

Comment: Woah.  Please format your code.  There is a button to do it and instructions on the post editing page.

Comment: sorry about that, i tried getting the code format thing to work but could not get any results =/ (the indent four spaces thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the url `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g34B-YOaC7c&ob=av2e` must be quoted as it contains a `&` use:

```
'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g34B-YOaC7c&ob=av2e'
```

Comment: thanks :) i knew about the qoutes part to escape the url, but im trying to make it so the script itself will automatically add the quotes instead of having to put them in yourself when you supply the url, would you know of a way to do that?

Comment: no, as you are passing the url on the command line it must be quoted or else the shell will interpret it; you could have your shell script read it from the tty after it starts, if it wasn't given one, and you wouldn't need to quote it there.

Comment: damn, what if i had the user input the url after the script has started, like say for instance via read, or some other method? or would it still not work? i plan on interfacing the script with apache2 after i get the workings of it down, but dont want to login to the machine to find find a couple hundred stopped processes because my friends/users werent putting quotes around the url lol

Comment: The `?` must also have a special meaning as its presence causes `bash` to eat/ignore the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Your command line

```
austin@Ruby:~$ ./meddownload.sh http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g34B-YOaC7c&ob=av2e
```

is seen by bash as two separate commands:

- ./meddownload.sh http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g34B-YOaC7c &
- ob=av2e

a commmand terminated by `&`, sending it to the background, followed by a simple shell variable assignment.

The first bit of output, `[1] 1001, is the shell notifying you that your first command was successfully sent to the background to run.

At your next prompt, you get the output from your backgrounded command:

```
Please specify your preferred file format by entering the number corresponding to the format name below
1:avi 2:mp3 3:aac 4:best(program will pick the the best audio format available (aac, mp3, m4a, wav, vorbis))
```

When you type `1` to make your selection, you aren't really sending it to the `read` command in your script. Because it is running in the background, you are really typing the `1` at the next prompt, which is why bash thinks you are trying to run the program `1` and responding

```
-bash: 1: command not found
```

Finally, your script in the background has reached the read command, and--as backgrounded process do when they attempt to read from stdin--stops until it is returned to the foreground:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 ./meddownload.sh http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g34B-YOaC7c
```

Answer (score 1):

See this? `g34B-YOaC7c&ob=av2e`

The shell is picking up the ampersand and putting the command in background.

Surround the URL with single quotes `'`

Comment: thanks :) i knew about the qoutes part to escape the url, but im trying to make it so the script itself will automatically add the quotes instead of having to put them in yourself when you supply the url, would you know of a way to do that?

Comment: @user1161841 The script never sees the &. It is interpreted by the shell before it is passed to your script as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

in bash the <kbd>&</kbd> sends a command to background .. that causes your error.

Quote the url fixes it

Comment: thanks :) i knew about the qoutes part to escape the url, but im trying to make it so the script itself will automatically add the quotes instead of having to put them in yourself when you supply the url, would you know of a way to do that?

Comment: damn, what if i had the user input the url after the script has started, like say for instance via read, or some other method? or would it still not work? i plan on interfacing the script with apache2 after i get the workings of it down, but dont want to login to the machine to find find a couple hundred stopped processes because my friends/users werent putting quotes around the url lol

Comment: I see the problem ;)  I think it should work with the read but I dont know exactly .. alternative you can write the urls to a file and process the file regularly